# Passing bash variable from gitlab-ci file as an extra argument to ansible job

Tags: python, bash, ansible, gitlab, cicd

I have a following problem.
I want to pass resolved IP addresses to this j2 template file:

```
COMMIT
# NAT table
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 636 -m statistic --mode nth --every 2 --packet 0 -j DNAT --to-destination {{ idm_ips[0] }}
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 636 -j DNAT --to-destination {{ idm_ips[1] }}
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

So my variables here are `idm_ips[0]` and `idm_ips[1]`.
They were set statically inside `ansible-vars.yaml` file:

```
idm_ips:
  - "192.168.10.25"
  - "192.168.10.42"
```

Now I have to resolve FQDNs to idm_ips dynamically, so I wrote a simple python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import socket
import json

ldap_dev = 'ldap.organisation.com'
resolved = socket.gethostbyname_ex(ldap_dev)
ips_arr = resolved[2]
idm_ips_json = json.dumps(ips_arr)
print(idm_ips_json)
```

This array of IPs is in JSON format, because I read on SO that if I want to pass a bash array as an extra argument to ansible job, it has to be JSON. So I did so.

1. I tried to pass thees values by storing them inside a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file as a bash variable:

```
- chmod +x ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/scripts/resolve_idm_dev.py
- idm_ips=`python3 ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/scripts/resolve_idm_dev.py`
```

2. And finally pass this variable to ansible as an extra argument:

```
ansible-playbook ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/ansible/provision.yml --extra-vars "project_path=${CI_PROJECT_DIR} project_environment=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME} '{"idm_ips": ${idm_ips}}'"
```

And I am struggling with it, because when I am trying to build my environment, I am getting an error:

```
fatal: [kibana-development]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: 'AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ''idm_ips'' is undefined'
```

What am I doing wrong? Could some good soul point me what to do?
Sorry for a fuzzy description.

Comment: Can you show use the that handles the template?

Comment: That's ansible job:

`- name: Copy firewall rules file
  become: yes
  template:
    src: "iptables-save.j2"
    dest: "/etc/sysconfig/iptables"
    mode: 0600
    owner: root
    group: root
  register: newfirewall
`

Answer (score 2):

First, tell python to escape `[`, `]` as they have special meaning in SHELL:

```
>>> print(json.dumps(socket.gethostbyname_ex("stackoverflow.com")[2]).replace("[","\\[").replace("]","\\]")) 
\["151.101.193.69", "151.101.129.69", "151.101.1.69", "151.101.65.69"\]
```

Second, properly handle the `JSON`:

```
ansible-playbook ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/ansible/provision.yml \
-e "project_path=${CI_PROJECT_DIR} \
-e project_environment=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME} \
-e '{"idm_ips":' "${idm_ips}"'}'
```

If this does not work, consider outputting `idm_ips_json` to a file and pass it with:

```
 ... -e @yourfile. # because working with json in the shell is terrible ..
```

Note, if you choose to work with your file, the content should be:

```
 {"idm_ips": ["192.X.Z.Y", "192."...]}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try to apply your solution and let you know if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunatelly same issue for first solution:
`msg: 'AnsibleUndefinedVariable: ''idm_ips'' is undefined'`

Will try with second one tomorrow.

Comment: `they have special meaning in SHELL:` No, don't. Do not use \` backticks, instead use `$(...)` and then just qoute the expansion like you did. They have meaning in shell in specific contexts - when the variable `"${idm_ips}"` is quoted, it's all fine. The quoting is off - you did not close first `"` and there's a space between `":' <here> "${idm` You meant. `-e "project_path=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
-e "project_environment=${CI_ENVIRONMENT_NAME}" -e "{ \"idm_ips\": $idm_ips }"`

Comment: You have the `"${idm_ips}"` enclosed in single quotes. Wouldn't that prevent expansion of variables? Is that intended?

Comment: I solved the problem. First I rewrote my script, so it produces yaml file, which is passed to ansible as an extra argument, but with short '-e' option, not as I tried in long one `--extra-vars`. It turned out, my arguments were ignored in that way as described in this issue: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/66971 Thank you all for your help and support :)